ROS2 control fourbarlinkage_transmission
I have built a closed loop mechanism, where 2 actuators are driving another 2 passive joints in a closed loop configuration. The joint and link arangements are defined as 2 separate chains:

joint11 (revolute) -> link11 -> joint12 (revolute) -> link12
joint21 (revolute) -> link22 -> joint22 (revolute) -> link22

link12 and link22 are then joined at the ends with a revolute joint, and an end-effector is attached to link22. Of course, close loop chain kinematics are not supported in URDF.
I am using ros2_control to control my 2 Dynamixel motors (at joint11 and joint 21). I saw that there is a FourBarLinkageTransmission which looks like it could be suitable to model this. However, the documentation on its implementation is pretty much non-existent. I reviewed the SimpleTransmission demo but it really isn't helpful. The C++ code seems far too opaque to work out what arguments to put in the xacro xml tags.
Does anyone have a working example of a four bar linkage transmission that they could provide?
